# Embedding VLC on Windows

Tags: qt4, vlc

How to access the webcam on windows (XP)?

On Linux, I'd use the MRL "v4l2://", as in:

```
libvlc_media_new(libvlc_new(),"v4l2://",&libvlc_exception_t)
```

And let it detect it automagically. I know, this could fail sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video for Linux's equivalent would be DirectShow which has the MRL of dshow:// however I have not got this working myself.